# Does anybody have a contact for the Docents for the Space Shuttles?

Tags: nasa, space-shuttle, ssme

I would like to pass along the following information to the Docents for Enterprise (Intrepid Sea, Air & Space Museum in New York) and Endeavour (Los Angeles Science Center). Documents describing the Space Shuttle and how it works:
https://aka.ms/space_shuttle

Feel free to pass it along or post a contact here and I will be more than happy to contact them.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a question about Space Exploration. I suggest the OP contacts the museums directly.

Comment: That's an impressive collection of information you've created!

Comment: It is indeed a massive amount of material. Worth to bookmark.

Comment: @Ludo, I have contacted the museums. No answers at all (not even a reply), I assume because of COVID. I know that there are members here that have direct contacts and I am asking for their help.